# Rsyslog: From a custom log file, Forward only the messages matching a pattern

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog

I want to forward messages matching a pattern (`HELLO` in this case) from a **custom** log file (`/home/ubuntu/test.log`) to a remote rsyslog server.

Here is the configuration:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/05-forwarding.conf
*.* @@rsyslogserver.mycompany.com:10514

# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/10-custom.conf
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputFileName /home/ubuntu/test.log
$InputFileTag testlogs:
$InputFileStateFile testlogs
$InputRunFileMonitor
:msg, contains, "HELLO" /var/log/testlog_error.log
& stop
:msg, !contains, "HELLO" stop
```

**Problem:**

1. All messages going to to the `/var/log/syslog`  has stopped. << **NOT GOOD**
2. Messages containing `HELLO` word in `/home/ubuntu/test.log` are going to `/var/log/testlog_error.log` as well as are getting forwarded to remote rsyslog server, << **GOOD**
3. Messages **NOT** containing `HELLO` word in `/home/ubuntu/test.log` are not going to `/var/log/testlog_error.log` which is **GOOD** but these messages are getting forwarded to remote rsyslog server. << **BAD**

My Ideal situation should be:

1. System and all other messages should continue to go to `/var/log/syslog`
2. No Change here. This is working as expected.
3. Messages **NOT** containing `HELLO` word in `/home/ubuntu/test.log` should completely get discarded. Don't write to local file as well as don't forward such messages to remote server.

Need help me in solving point 1 and point 3 above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it is, your file **/etc/rsyslog.d/05-forwarding.conf** is forwarding all messages passing thought, and not only messages from your custom file **/home/ubuntu/test.log**. So, you can **delete** it, as you said you only want to forward messages from your custom file.

Your file **/etc/rsyslog.d/10-custom.conf** must looks like:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputFileName /home/ubuntu/test.log
$InputFileTag testlogs:
$InputFileStateFile testlogs
$InputFileFacility local0
$InputRunFileMonitor

:syslogtag, isequal, "testlogs:" {
  :msg, contains, "HELLO" {
    local0.* /var/log/testlog_error.log
    local0.* @@rsyslogserver.mycompany.com:10514
  }
  stop
}
```

As you can see, I added the following:

> $InputFileFacility local0

Now your custom file will be monitored, and it messages will be written in local0 facility. Messages from local0 will have the tag that you associated to it.

> :syslogtag, isequal, "testlogs:"

This rule will only match a message that contains the tag testlogs:, that is exactly the messages you want. So, all other messages will skip it, and be logged in /var/log/syslog and everything else from 50-default.conf.

> :msg, contains, "HELLO"

Now, all messages from your file that contains HELLO, will be logged in /var/log/testlog_error.log and forwarded to @@rsyslogserver.mycompany.com:10514.

And then, the "stop" will discard all messages from your file that are being written in local0.